# Sequence with recurrence relation in C#

Tags: c#

The problem N°7

[image]

I'm new here, it's my first question, please be tolerant enough.

What we've took so far are for and while loop.

Edit: That's not a homework.
I can't think of anything, we have had a similar problem in class and there we tried to switch the variables, and i tried that here, but it didn't work, and by the way it isn't a homework, that's a problem in an exam which i'm trying to prepare for it.

And if you don't want to solve it, please tell me how to attack it, i always stumbles upon sequence problems.
Thank you

Comment: Post what you've tried so far and what problems you're having. We're not going to do your homework for you.

Comment: We're not doing that here

Comment: I can't think of anything, we have had a similar problem in class and there we tried to switch the variables, and i tried that here, but it didn't work, and by the way it isn't a homework, that's a problem in an exam which i'm trying to prepare for it

Comment: [And do not post images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: Step-by-step: can you compute U4? Once you have U4 can you compute U5? Continue from there. Don't get stuck on recursion or fancy structures. Just do the first step, then the second, and see how you can make it cleaner after it's working.

Comment: but when i try to get U5, i get U(-2) and U(-1) which i think not allowed

Comment: Screenshots of _text_ are acceptable - it's screenshots of _code_ that are frowned upon.

Comment: U5 should be a function of U1, U2, U3, and U4. I'm not sure where you are getting U(-2) and U(-1)

Comment: D Stanley- Yes i tried to write in LaTex here the problem to not post an image, but it didn't work

Comment: Don't worry about it - that screenshot is fine (and SO doesn't support LaTeX)

Comment: D Stanley- U5 is U(1+4) so n=1, then i plug n in the recurrence relation, then you got U(-2)

Comment: Or, think of U as a function with 4 variables (forget the sequence for now). Once you get that result you can take it along with the three other variables that were inputs and compute the next value.

Comment: Then I think the equation is written wrong. The result should either be Un or those should be U(n+1) and U(n+2). Ask your professor.

Comment: Yes that's the method we used to the similar problem in class, i tried it, but i didn't arrive to anything

Comment: D Stanley- That's a problem in an exam in 2020, so i think it's not wrong, nevertheless i'll ask my professor thank you

Comment: `U1`...`U4` are your initial conditions. The problem specifically says that `n > 3`. So, there's no opportunity to evaluate U for some negative value. U5 is simple a function of U1...U4.

Comment: @3Dave *U0..U3 it is.

Comment: 3Dave- then what is U5 in terms of U1.. U4? Because n=1 in U5 and n>3 so..

Comment: Fildor- How it's not? please enlighten me

Comment: Ah, wait... Now I get your confusion. Yes, it's written really small, but it's also nonsense. The Formula is messed up.

Comment: _That_ is from an exam?? Would be interesting how many students failed. This is complete and utter nonsense. You could try and "fix" it, but with a 50/50 % Cance of getting it wrong.

Comment: The problem is very poorly-written. As written, the first term you could calculate would be U8 (since `n > 3`), and U0 would be completely ignored.

Comment: It's either `U_(n+4) = 2U_(n+3) + (-1)^(n+4) * U_(n+2) - 3 * U_(n+1) + 2 * U_n` where n >= 0 _OR_ `U_n = 2U_(n-4) + (-1)^n * U_(n-3) - 3 * U_(n-2) + 2 * U_(n-1)` where n > 3

Comment: I'll ask my professor, and i'll leave this problem for now, thank you all

Comment: Don't start with code! Start calculating U_4, using 1, 2, 3 as U_0. U_1, U_2. Then go to U_5 (that needs U_4). By understanding that, start writing the code that does the same as you did before with simple Math.

Comment: @GustavoGarcia Read the formula again: U_4 depends on U_0, UU_-1, U_-2, U_-3. It is nonsense.

Comment: @netMage You are right. The smaller possible number would be U_7 (n=3) that will depends on U_0 to U_4. And there will be no recursion on that.

Comment: So what part of the assignment are you having trouble with. Please [edit] your question with the specific part you want to ask about. [SO] is not a code writing service, and you have described three phases of the assignment. a) inputs, b) calculation and c) outputs. Where is **your** question in all of this?

Answer (score 0):

Without any consideration for the inputs (that is left to the author) the code below stores the 4-th previous values in variable `u_0`, `u_1`, `u_2`, and `u_3`, and the current value in `u`.

Then in a loop in updates all the values. The loop is repeated `n-3` times because to get `n=4` you need at least one iteration.

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int n = 8;
        Console.WriteLine($"n={n}");
        int u_3 = 2, u_2 = -1, u_1=1, u_0=0;
        int u = 0;
        Console.WriteLine($"u_{0} = {u_0}");
        Console.WriteLine($"u_{1} = {u_1}");
        Console.WriteLine($"u_{2} = {u_2}");
        Console.WriteLine($"u_{3} = {u_3}");
        for (int i = 0; i < n-3; i++)
        {
            // (-1)^(i+4) is 1 when i+4 is even, and -1 otherwise.
            int sign = (i + 4) % 2 == 0 ? 1 : -1;
            u = 2 * u_0 - 3 * u_1 + sign * u_2 + 2 * u_3;
            Console.WriteLine($"u_{i+4} = {u}");
            u_0 = u_1;
            u_1 = u_2;
            u_2 = u_3;
            u_3 = u;
        }
    }
}
```

Output is

```
n=8
u_0 = 0
u_1 = 1
u_2 = -1
u_3 = 2
u_4 = 0
u_5 = 3
u_6 = -2
u_7 = -3
u_8 = -17
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the following equation...

> U(n+4) = 2U(n+3) + (-1)^(n+4) U(n+2) - 3U(n+1) + 2U(n)

which can be simplified to...

> U4 = 2U3 + (-1)^(n) U2 - 3U1 + 2U0

Adding more to the [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75227013/9444282) of [John Alexiou](https://stackoverflow.com/users/380384/john-alexiou)

```
int u0 = 0, u1 = 0, u2 = 0, u3 = 0, un = 0, n = 0;
while (true)
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter U0, U1, U2, U3, and n separated by spaces:");
        string[] inputs = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');

        u0 = int.Parse(inputs[0]);
        u1 = int.Parse(inputs[1]);
        u2 = int.Parse(inputs[2]);
        u3 = int.Parse(inputs[3]);
        n = int.Parse(inputs[4]);

        if (n >= 4)
            break;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Try again! Please enter valid integers values for U0, U1, U2, U3 and n > 4\n");
    }

for (int i = 4; i <= n; i++)
{
    var sign = i % 2 == 0 ? 1 : -1;

    un = 2 * u3 + sign * u2 - 3 * u1 + 2 * u0;
    u0 = u1; u1 = u2; u2 = u3; u3 = un;
}

Console.WriteLine($"U{n} = {un}");
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like,

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var u0 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        var u1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        var u2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        var u3 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        var ng3 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        
        if (ng3 < 3) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(ng3));
        
        for (int i = 4; i <= ng3; i++)
        {
            var u4 = (2 * u3) + ((-1)^i)*(u2 - (3 * u1) + (2 * u0));
            u0 = u1;
            u1 = u2;
            u2 = u3;
            u3 = u4;
        }
        
        Console.WriteLine(u3);
    }
}
```

It my be possible to create the identity function for the series and lose the loop.